# Why define vector decomposition in terms of an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I can already find the components of any vector in a vector space with respect to some basis by finding the coefficients in front of each basis vector. However I've seen some people define the components of a vector in terms of the inner product of the basis vectors and the vector you're trying to decompose.

These two approaches are equal, so why would you use the inner product approach if the basis coefficient approach requires less assumptions? (It isn't dependent on the presence of an inner product).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean here? How do people define the components of a vector in terms of an inner product? This is difficult to do, unless the basis is orthonormal. Could you also clarify the method you usually use to compute the coefficients of a vector with respect to a basis?

Comment: The inner product is.a way to resolve the components of a vector. A method of computation is not a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the vector may not be written out explicitly in a component-wise format.
Or, it might be the case that we'd like to project our vector $\vec{v}=a\hat{x}+ b\hat{y}$ into a different (e.g. rotated or skewed coordinate system). In this case, we must write out the new basis vectors in terms of the old, and take the inner product. We do not have the luxury of reading off the components in all cases.